# Oracle returns invalid number of rows on json_table

Tags: json, oracle, json-table

When I run following query on Oracle 19, it returns 28 record instead of 30, and I cannot understand why, as I am expecting 30 records:

```
select *
  from json_table('{"values":[[1,120674124,200000000,838654366,564288,100000000,419327183,505596,8400000,335460,10063848,1300680,99335724,168528,0,0,0,0,0],
  [2,126739164,210000000,897502964,544740,105000000,448751482,554376,3780000,358992,4480116,888180,112167972,184788,3780000,0,0,0,0],
  [3,133130616,220500000,970973099,550812,110250000,485486549,622968,3969000,388380,4920396,788340,117714072,207648,3969000,0,0,0,0],
  [4,139806252,231525000,1035145287,567648,115762500,517572643,668448,4167444,414048,5139432,827088,123631896,222804,4167444,0,0,0,0],
  [5,146842056,243101250,1109915313,573948,121550625,554957656,735984,4375812,443964,5555376,691104,129844740,245316,4375812,0,0,0,0],
  [6,154208088,255256312,1165411077,591588,127628156,582705538,790728,4594608,0,1886592,539184,140947212,263568,4594608,0,0,0,0],
  [7,161931576,268019127,1223681630,621504,134009563,611840815,840084,4824336,0,1904796,563484,148073016,280020,4824336,0,0,0,0],
  [8,170041944,281420083,1284865711,652920,140710041,642432855,892428,5065560,0,1871364,586812,155609832,297468,5065560,0,0,0,0],
  [9,178558572,295491087,1349108995,685932,147745543,674554497,947952,5318832,0,1894632,613800,163462620,315972,5318832,0,0,0,0],
  [10,187515948,310265641,1416564445,776052,155132820,708282222,1017432,5584776,0,1885812,643716,171684252,339132,5584776,0,0,0,0],
  [11,196907940,325778923,1487392666,844440,162889461,743696333,1080444,3909336,0,1130172,558972,183160416,360144,5864016,0,0,0,0],
  [12,206770416,342067869,1561762299,978972,171033934,780881149,1147272,4104804,0,867960,578052,192553728,382416,6157212,0,0,0,0],
  [13,217159740,359171262,1639850412,1092876,179585631,819925206,1242744,4310052,0,592632,598344,202443780,414240,6465072,0,0,0,0],
  [14,228045444,377129825,1721842931,1249656,188564912,860921465,1325664,4525548,0,303540,620256,212790564,441888,6788328,0,0,0,0],
  [15,240046536,395986316,1807935075,1401864,197993158,903967537,1434276,4751832,0,0,666948,223643400,478092,7127748,197993158,903967537,406788,135588],
  [16,252098868,415785631,1898331825,1585032,207892815,949165912,1543500,4989420,0,0,707208,234705588,514488,7484136,207892815,949165912,427128,142368],
  [17,264796704,436574912,1993248413,1763736,218287456,996624206,1690344,5238888,0,0,750720,246333264,563436,7858344,218287456,996624206,448488,149484],
  [18,278113452,458403657,2092910831,1977216,229201828,1046455415,1832544,5500836,0,0,796824,258516060,610848,8251260,229201828,1046455415,470904,156960],
  [19,292133640,481323839,2197556370,2186376,240661919,1098778185,2010060,5775876,0,0,846204,271322028,670020,8663820,240661919,1098778185,494448,164808],
  [20,306872916,505390030,2307434187,2389104,252695015,1153717093,2210004,6064680,0,0,898092,284785128,736668,9097020,252695015,1153717093,519168,173052],
  [21,322356636,530659531,2422805893,2606952,265329765,1211402946,2425560,3183948,0,0,818148,302234808,808512,9551868,265329765,1211402946,545136,181704],
  [22,338674188,557192507,2543946186,2866104,278596253,1271973093,2696628,3343152,0,0,872988,317203812,898872,10029456,278596253,1271973093,572388,190788],
  [23,355846248,585052132,2671143492,3039396,292526066,1335571746,3010224,3510312,0,0,928008,333022632,1003404,10530936,292526066,1335571746,601008,200328],
  [24,373890684,614304738,2804700666,3278532,307152369,1402350333,3349824,3685824,0,0,988788,349572228,1116600,11057484,307152369,1402350333,631056,210348],
  [25,392897280,645019974,2944935696,3563520,322509987,1472467848,3751368,3870108,0,0,1056588,366911424,1250448,11610348,322509987,1472467848,662616,220860],
  [26,412920252,677270972,3092182479,3807876,338635486,1546091239,4222512,4063620,0,0,1128252,385171968,1407504,12190872,338635486,1546091239,695736,231912],
  [27,434000436,711134520,3246791602,4068012,355567260,1623395801,4759272,4266804,0,0,1206012,404339484,1586412,12800412,355567260,1623395801,730524,243504],
  [28,456213816,746691246,3409131180,4344924,373345623,1704565590,5382252,4480140,0,0,1291188,424458072,1794072,13440432,373345623,1704565590,767052,255684],
  [29,479662344,784025808,3579587737,4711032,392012904,1789793868,6129744,4704144,0,0,1389096,445498764,2043240,14112456,392012904,1789793868,805404,268464],
  [30,504303660,823227098,3758567122,5028468,411613549,1879283561,6929868,4939356,0,0,1489920,467660448,2309952,14818080,411613549,1879283561,845676,281892]]}',
                   '$.values[*]'
                    columns(x1 number path '$[0]', x2 number path '$[1]', x3 number path '$[2]', x4 number path '$[3]', x5 number path '$[4]',
                            x6 number path '$[5]', x7 number path '$[6]', x8 number path '$[7]', x9 number path '$[8]', x10 number path '$[9]',
                            x11 number path '$[10]', x12 number path '$[11]', x13 number path '$[12]', x14 number path '$[13]', x15 number path '$[14]',
                            x16 number path '$[15]', x17 number path '$[16]', x18 number path '$[17]', x19 number path '$[18]'))
```

if I remove some of rows from the json then last rows (29, and 30) are returned in query result, and as you see all rows have exactly 19 numbers.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Tested in 19 and 21: both returning 30 rows.
"Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.22.0.1.0" and "Oracle Database 21c Enterprise Edition Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 21.3.0.0.0"

Comment: @p3consulting It is replicated on Oracle 18 in the fiddle linked at the bottom of my answer. If I change the fiddle version to [Oracle 21](https://dbfiddle.uk/9LHFgGJX) then the same query that gives a partial result set on oracle 18 instead fails with `ORA-01704: string literal too long`.

Comment: indeed in these 2 instances I tested (Cloud ones) the max_string_size is EXTENDED.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your string is too long.

Stripping all the white-space then:

```sql
SELECT LENGTH(
         '{"values":[[1,120674124,200000000,838654366,564288,100000000,419327183,505596,8400000,335460,10063848,1300680,99335724,168528,0,0,0,0,0],[2,126739164,210000000,897502964,544740,105000000,448751482,554376,3780000,358992,4480116,888180,112167972,184788,3780000,0,0,0,0],[3,133130616,220500000,970973099,550812,110250000,485486549,622968,3969000,388380,4920396,788340,117714072,207648,3969000,0,0,0,0],[4,139806252,231525000,1035145287,567648,115762500,517572643,668448,4167444,414048,5139432,827088,123631896,222804,4167444,0,0,0,0],[5,146842056,243101250,1109915313,573948,121550625,554957656,735984,4375812,443964,5555376,691104,129844740,245316,4375812,0,0,0,0],[6,154208088,255256312,1165411077,591588,127628156,582705538,790728,4594608,0,1886592,539184,140947212,263568,4594608,0,0,0,0],[7,161931576,268019127,1223681630,621504,134009563,611840815,840084,4824336,0,1904796,563484,148073016,280020,4824336,0,0,0,0],[8,170041944,281420083,1284865711,652920,140710041,642432855,892428,5065560,0,1871364,586812,155609832,297468,5065560,0,0,0,0],[9,178558572,295491087,1349108995,685932,147745543,674554497,947952,5318832,0,1894632,613800,163462620,315972,5318832,0,0,0,0],[10,187515948,310265641,1416564445,776052,155132820,708282222,1017432,5584776,0,1885812,643716,171684252,339132,5584776,0,0,0,0],[11,196907940,325778923,1487392666,844440,162889461,743696333,1080444,3909336,0,1130172,558972,183160416,360144,5864016,0,0,0,0],[12,206770416,342067869,1561762299,978972,171033934,780881149,1147272,4104804,0,867960,578052,192553728,382416,6157212,0,0,0,0],[13,217159740,359171262,1639850412,1092876,179585631,819925206,1242744,4310052,0,592632,598344,202443780,414240,6465072,0,0,0,0],[14,228045444,377129825,1721842931,1249656,188564912,860921465,1325664,4525548,0,303540,620256,212790564,441888,6788328,0,0,0,0],[15,240046536,395986316,1807935075,1401864,197993158,903967537,1434276,4751832,0,0,666948,223643400,478092,7127748,197993158,903967537,406788,135588],[16,252098868,415785631,1898331825,1585032,207892815,949165912,1543500,4989420,0,0,707208,234705588,514488,7484136,207892815,949165912,427128,142368],[17,264796704,436574912,1993248413,1763736,218287456,996624206,1690344,5238888,0,0,750720,246333264,563436,7858344,218287456,996624206,448488,149484],[18,278113452,458403657,2092910831,1977216,229201828,1046455415,1832544,5500836,0,0,796824,258516060,610848,8251260,229201828,1046455415,470904,156960],[19,292133640,481323839,2197556370,2186376,240661919,1098778185,2010060,5775876,0,0,846204,271322028,670020,8663820,240661919,1098778185,494448,164808],[20,306872916,505390030,2307434187,2389104,252695015,1153717093,2210004,6064680,0,0,898092,284785128,736668,9097020,252695015,1153717093,519168,173052],[21,322356636,530659531,2422805893,2606952,265329765,1211402946,2425560,3183948,0,0,818148,302234808,808512,9551868,265329765,1211402946,545136,181704],[22,338674188,557192507,2543946186,2866104,278596253,1271973093,2696628,3343152,0,0,872988,317203812,898872,10029456,278596253,1271973093,572388,190788],[23,355846248,585052132,2671143492,3039396,292526066,1335571746,3010224,3510312,0,0,928008,333022632,1003404,10530936,292526066,1335571746,601008,200328],[24,373890684,614304738,2804700666,3278532,307152369,1402350333,3349824,3685824,0,0,988788,349572228,1116600,11057484,307152369,1402350333,631056,210348],[25,392897280,645019974,2944935696,3563520,322509987,1472467848,3751368,3870108,0,0,1056588,366911424,1250448,11610348,322509987,1472467848,662616,220860],[26,412920252,677270972,3092182479,3807876,338635486,1546091239,4222512,4063620,0,0,1128252,385171968,1407504,12190872,338635486,1546091239,695736,231912],[27,434000436,711134520,3246791602,4068012,355567260,1623395801,4759272,4266804,0,0,1206012,404339484,1586412,12800412,355567260,1623395801,730524,243504],[28,456213816,746691246,3409131180,4344924,373345623,1704565590,5382252,4480140,0,0,1291188,424458072,1794072,13440432,373345623,1704565590,767052,255684],[29,479662344,784025808,3579587737,4711032,392012904,1789793868,6129744,4704144,0,0,1389096,445498764,2043240,14112456,392012904,1789793868,805404,268464],[30,504303660,823227098,3758567122,5028468,411613549,1879283561,6929868,4939356,0,0,1489920,467660448,2309952,14818080,411613549,1879283561,845676,281892]]}'
       ) AS len
FROM   DUAL
```

Outputs:

> ```
> ORA-01704: string literal too long
> ```

Because the string is 4266 characters long and `VARCHAR2` (and literals) are limited to 4000 bytes.

Why your query does not throw that syntax error, I do not know; but it may be a bug.

If you do:

```sql
select *
from json_table(
       EMPTY_CLOB()
       || '{"values":[
          [1,120674124,200000000,838654366,564288,100000000,419327183,505596,8400000,335460,10063848,1300680,99335724,168528,0,0,0,0,0],
          [2,126739164,210000000,897502964,544740,105000000,448751482,554376,3780000,358992,4480116,888180,112167972,184788,3780000,0,0,0,0],
          [3,133130616,220500000,970973099,550812,110250000,485486549,622968,3969000,388380,4920396,788340,117714072,207648,3969000,0,0,0,0],
          [4,139806252,231525000,1035145287,567648,115762500,517572643,668448,4167444,414048,5139432,827088,123631896,222804,4167444,0,0,0,0],
          [5,146842056,243101250,1109915313,573948,121550625,554957656,735984,4375812,443964,5555376,691104,129844740,245316,4375812,0,0,0,0],
          [6,154208088,255256312,1165411077,591588,127628156,582705538,790728,4594608,0,1886592,539184,140947212,263568,4594608,0,0,0,0],
          [7,161931576,268019127,1223681630,621504,134009563,611840815,840084,4824336,0,1904796,563484,148073016,280020,4824336,0,0,0,0],
          [8,170041944,281420083,1284865711,652920,140710041,642432855,892428,5065560,0,1871364,586812,155609832,297468,5065560,0,0,0,0],
          [9,178558572,295491087,1349108995,685932,147745543,674554497,947952,5318832,0,1894632,613800,163462620,315972,5318832,0,0,0,0],
          [10,187515948,310265641,1416564445,776052,155132820,708282222,1017432,5584776,0,1885812,643716,171684252,339132,5584776,0,0,0,0],
          [11,196907940,325778923,1487392666,844440,162889461,743696333,1080444,3909336,0,1130172,558972,183160416,360144,5864016,0,0,0,0],
          [12,206770416,342067869,1561762299,978972,171033934,780881149,1147272,4104804,0,867960,578052,192553728,382416,6157212,0,0,0,0],
          [13,217159740,359171262,1639850412,1092876,179585631,819925206,1242744,4310052,0,592632,598344,202443780,414240,6465072,0,0,0,0],
          [14,228045444,377129825,1721842931,1249656,188564912,860921465,1325664,4525548,0,303540,620256,212790564,441888,6788328,0,0,0,0],
          [15,240046536,395986316,1807935075,1401864,197993158,903967537,1434276,4751832,0,0,666948,223643400,478092,7127748,197993158,903967537,406788,135588],
    ' || '[16,252098868,415785631,1898331825,1585032,207892815,949165912,1543500,4989420,0,0,707208,234705588,514488,7484136,207892815,949165912,427128,142368],
          [17,264796704,436574912,1993248413,1763736,218287456,996624206,1690344,5238888,0,0,750720,246333264,563436,7858344,218287456,996624206,448488,149484],
          [18,278113452,458403657,2092910831,1977216,229201828,1046455415,1832544,5500836,0,0,796824,258516060,610848,8251260,229201828,1046455415,470904,156960],
          [19,292133640,481323839,2197556370,2186376,240661919,1098778185,2010060,5775876,0,0,846204,271322028,670020,8663820,240661919,1098778185,494448,164808],
          [20,306872916,505390030,2307434187,2389104,252695015,1153717093,2210004,6064680,0,0,898092,284785128,736668,9097020,252695015,1153717093,519168,173052],
          [21,322356636,530659531,2422805893,2606952,265329765,1211402946,2425560,3183948,0,0,818148,302234808,808512,9551868,265329765,1211402946,545136,181704],
          [22,338674188,557192507,2543946186,2866104,278596253,1271973093,2696628,3343152,0,0,872988,317203812,898872,10029456,278596253,1271973093,572388,190788],
          [23,355846248,585052132,2671143492,3039396,292526066,1335571746,3010224,3510312,0,0,928008,333022632,1003404,10530936,292526066,1335571746,601008,200328],
          [24,373890684,614304738,2804700666,3278532,307152369,1402350333,3349824,3685824,0,0,988788,349572228,1116600,11057484,307152369,1402350333,631056,210348],
          [25,392897280,645019974,2944935696,3563520,322509987,1472467848,3751368,3870108,0,0,1056588,366911424,1250448,11610348,322509987,1472467848,662616,220860],
          [26,412920252,677270972,3092182479,3807876,338635486,1546091239,4222512,4063620,0,0,1128252,385171968,1407504,12190872,338635486,1546091239,695736,231912],
          [27,434000436,711134520,3246791602,4068012,355567260,1623395801,4759272,4266804,0,0,1206012,404339484,1586412,12800412,355567260,1623395801,730524,243504],
          [28,456213816,746691246,3409131180,4344924,373345623,1704565590,5382252,4480140,0,0,1291188,424458072,1794072,13440432,373345623,1704565590,767052,255684],
          [29,479662344,784025808,3579587737,4711032,392012904,1789793868,6129744,4704144,0,0,1389096,445498764,2043240,14112456,392012904,1789793868,805404,268464],
          [30,504303660,823227098,3758567122,5028468,411613549,1879283561,6929868,4939356,0,0,1489920,467660448,2309952,14818080,411613549,1879283561,845676,281892]
        ]}',
      '$.values[*]'
      columns(
        x1 number path '$[0]',
        x2 number path '$[1]',
        x3 number path '$[2]',
        x4 number path '$[3]',
        x5 number path '$[4]',
        x6 number path '$[5]',
        x7 number path '$[6]',
        x8 number path '$[7]',
        x9 number path '$[8]',
        x10 number path '$[9]',
        x11 number path '$[10]',
        x12 number path '$[11]',
        x13 number path '$[12]',
        x14 number path '$[13]',
        x15 number path '$[14]',
        x16 number path '$[15]',
        x17 number path '$[16]',
        x18 number path '$[17]',
        x19 number path '$[18]'
      )
    )
```

*(Which, due to the white-spaces, is an even longer string but is created from two shorter literals concatenated to an empty CLOB.)*

Then the output is all 30 rows:

| X1 | X2 | X3 | X4 | X5 | X6 | X7 | X8 | X9 | X10 | X11 | X12 | X13 | X14 | X15 | X16 | X17 | X18 | X19 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 120674124 | 200000000 | 838654366 | 564288 | 100000000 | 419327183 | 505596 | 8400000 | 335460 | 10063848 | 1300680 | 99335724 | 168528 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 126739164 | 210000000 | 897502964 | 544740 | 105000000 | 448751482 | 554376 | 3780000 | 358992 | 4480116 | 888180 | 112167972 | 184788 | 3780000 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 133130616 | 220500000 | 970973099 | 550812 | 110250000 | 485486549 | 622968 | 3969000 | 388380 | 4920396 | 788340 | 117714072 | 207648 | 3969000 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 139806252 | 231525000 | 1035145287 | 567648 | 115762500 | 517572643 | 668448 | 4167444 | 414048 | 5139432 | 827088 | 123631896 | 222804 | 4167444 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 146842056 | 243101250 | 1109915313 | 573948 | 121550625 | 554957656 | 735984 | 4375812 | 443964 | 5555376 | 691104 | 129844740 | 245316 | 4375812 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 6 | 154208088 | 255256312 | 1165411077 | 591588 | 127628156 | 582705538 | 790728 | 4594608 | 0 | 1886592 | 539184 | 140947212 | 263568 | 4594608 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 7 | 161931576 | 268019127 | 1223681630 | 621504 | 134009563 | 611840815 | 840084 | 4824336 | 0 | 1904796 | 563484 | 148073016 | 280020 | 4824336 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 8 | 170041944 | 281420083 | 1284865711 | 652920 | 140710041 | 642432855 | 892428 | 5065560 | 0 | 1871364 | 586812 | 155609832 | 297468 | 5065560 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 9 | 178558572 | 295491087 | 1349108995 | 685932 | 147745543 | 674554497 | 947952 | 5318832 | 0 | 1894632 | 613800 | 163462620 | 315972 | 5318832 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 10 | 187515948 | 310265641 | 1416564445 | 776052 | 155132820 | 708282222 | 1017432 | 5584776 | 0 | 1885812 | 643716 | 171684252 | 339132 | 5584776 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 11 | 196907940 | 325778923 | 1487392666 | 844440 | 162889461 | 743696333 | 1080444 | 3909336 | 0 | 1130172 | 558972 | 183160416 | 360144 | 5864016 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 12 | 206770416 | 342067869 | 1561762299 | 978972 | 171033934 | 780881149 | 1147272 | 4104804 | 0 | 867960 | 578052 | 192553728 | 382416 | 6157212 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 13 | 217159740 | 359171262 | 1639850412 | 1092876 | 179585631 | 819925206 | 1242744 | 4310052 | 0 | 592632 | 598344 | 202443780 | 414240 | 6465072 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 14 | 228045444 | 377129825 | 1721842931 | 1249656 | 188564912 | 860921465 | 1325664 | 4525548 | 0 | 303540 | 620256 | 212790564 | 441888 | 6788328 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 15 | 240046536 | 395986316 | 1807935075 | 1401864 | 197993158 | 903967537 | 1434276 | 4751832 | 0 | 0 | 666948 | 223643400 | 478092 | 7127748 | 197993158 | 903967537 | 406788 | 135588 |
| 16 | 252098868 | 415785631 | 1898331825 | 1585032 | 207892815 | 949165912 | 1543500 | 4989420 | 0 | 0 | 707208 | 234705588 | 514488 | 7484136 | 207892815 | 949165912 | 427128 | 142368 |
| 17 | 264796704 | 436574912 | 1993248413 | 1763736 | 218287456 | 996624206 | 1690344 | 5238888 | 0 | 0 | 750720 | 246333264 | 563436 | 7858344 | 218287456 | 996624206 | 448488 | 149484 |
| 18 | 278113452 | 458403657 | 2092910831 | 1977216 | 229201828 | 1046455415 | 1832544 | 5500836 | 0 | 0 | 796824 | 258516060 | 610848 | 8251260 | 229201828 | 1046455415 | 470904 | 156960 |
| 19 | 292133640 | 481323839 | 2197556370 | 2186376 | 240661919 | 1098778185 | 2010060 | 5775876 | 0 | 0 | 846204 | 271322028 | 670020 | 8663820 | 240661919 | 1098778185 | 494448 | 164808 |
| 20 | 306872916 | 505390030 | 2307434187 | 2389104 | 252695015 | 1153717093 | 2210004 | 6064680 | 0 | 0 | 898092 | 284785128 | 736668 | 9097020 | 252695015 | 1153717093 | 519168 | 173052 |
| 21 | 322356636 | 530659531 | 2422805893 | 2606952 | 265329765 | 1211402946 | 2425560 | 3183948 | 0 | 0 | 818148 | 302234808 | 808512 | 9551868 | 265329765 | 1211402946 | 545136 | 181704 |
| 22 | 338674188 | 557192507 | 2543946186 | 2866104 | 278596253 | 1271973093 | 2696628 | 3343152 | 0 | 0 | 872988 | 317203812 | 898872 | 10029456 | 278596253 | 1271973093 | 572388 | 190788 |
| 23 | 355846248 | 585052132 | 2671143492 | 3039396 | 292526066 | 1335571746 | 3010224 | 3510312 | 0 | 0 | 928008 | 333022632 | 1003404 | 10530936 | 292526066 | 1335571746 | 601008 | 200328 |
| 24 | 373890684 | 614304738 | 2804700666 | 3278532 | 307152369 | 1402350333 | 3349824 | 3685824 | 0 | 0 | 988788 | 349572228 | 1116600 | 11057484 | 307152369 | 1402350333 | 631056 | 210348 |
| 25 | 392897280 | 645019974 | 2944935696 | 3563520 | 322509987 | 1472467848 | 3751368 | 3870108 | 0 | 0 | 1056588 | 366911424 | 1250448 | 11610348 | 322509987 | 1472467848 | 662616 | 220860 |
| 26 | 412920252 | 677270972 | 3092182479 | 3807876 | 338635486 | 1546091239 | 4222512 | 4063620 | 0 | 0 | 1128252 | 385171968 | 1407504 | 12190872 | 338635486 | 1546091239 | 695736 | 231912 |
| 27 | 434000436 | 711134520 | 3246791602 | 4068012 | 355567260 | 1623395801 | 4759272 | 4266804 | 0 | 0 | 1206012 | 404339484 | 1586412 | 12800412 | 355567260 | 1623395801 | 730524 | 243504 |
| 28 | 456213816 | 746691246 | 3409131180 | 4344924 | 373345623 | 1704565590 | 5382252 | 4480140 | 0 | 0 | 1291188 | 424458072 | 1794072 | 13440432 | 373345623 | 1704565590 | 767052 | 255684 |
| 29 | 479662344 | 784025808 | 3579587737 | 4711032 | 392012904 | 1789793868 | 6129744 | 4704144 | 0 | 0 | 1389096 | 445498764 | 2043240 | 14112456 | 392012904 | 1789793868 | 805404 | 268464 |
| 30 | 504303660 | 823227098 | 3758567122 | 5028468 | 411613549 | 1879283561 | 6929868 | 4939356 | 0 | 0 | 1489920 | 467660448 | 2309952 | 14818080 | 411613549 | 1879283561 | 845676 | 281892 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Mzgj6eGJ)